# different 404 for subdirectory when paths are handled by index.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, drupal, http-status-code-404, subdirectory

I'd like `/blog/anything-that-doesn't-exist` to redirect to `/blog`, while any other 404s are handled by Drupal.

My htaccess currently has:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

So everything is handled by Drupal. Is it possible to have a subdirectory specific 404 rule, but set that from the root directory htaccess? The `/blog/` subdirectory is generated by Drupal, so I can't put an overriding htaccess in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in your Root/.htaccess file :

```
 RewriteEngine On


#If /blog/foo is not a directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/blog/$1 !-d
#And /blog/foo is not a file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/blog/$1 !-f
#Then redirect /blog/foo to /blog
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ /blog/ [NC,L,R]
```

It is worth noting that, the Execution time of RewriteRule and ErrorDocument directive is diffrent. RewriteRule directive executes before the ErrorDocument directive, so any request for /blog/bad_url will be handled by the rule above, and all other 404 requests will be handled by the ErrorDocument.